# Should I use puzzling or puzzled?

Tags: grammar

> The child was clearly **puzzling** at **being addressed** in such a grown-up way.

There is an error in the sentence, but I don't know where. I wonder whether I should change **puzzling** to **puzzled** like this:

> The child was clearly **puzzled** at **being addressed** in such a grown-up way.

or change **being** to **be** like this:

> The child was clearly **puzzling** at **be addressed** in such a grown-up way.

I think I should use **be** after **at**, and I'm not sure that **puzzling** in the sentence is correct.

Kindly help, I am really puzzled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the child is not puzzling (which means other people would be puzzled by the child!)

And as for be/being, the child is *being* addressed, which is what the child is puzzled at or wondering about.

So the correct sentence is:

> The child was puzzled at being addressed in such a grown-up way.

Comment: At the risk of muddying this answer, which is quite correct, I will observe that "puzzling" can also be a verb that means attempting to work out an answer to something.  "Puzzling at", however, wouldn't be typical; "puzzle over" means to go over a problem, presumably with a goal of solving it, and "puzzle out" means to work out an answer to a problem.  So, I might puzzle over a complicated piece of software code to understand what it is doing, and I might then puzzle out the source of a bug in the code and fix it.